# How to find property of specific class that I want in xcode code sense

Tags: xcode, code-completion

When I use a code sense(dot notation) with pushing 'escape' key right behind 'dot', there are so many properties that can use like below image:

[image: cose sense]

What I want is that this drop down list show only specific class's property.
For example, on this image I want to see UITableViewCellAccessoryType class's properties only.
Or any other class if I want. void, UIButton, UIView, ... etc.